# Sending data from mule flow to ajax using Mule CE 3.5.0

Tags: ajax, mule, esb

I did a test with ajax in Mule CE 3.5.0 which is detecting a click on images, and send this information to my mule project, if i click on a play image i get a message "play" ... What i want now is an example of how to send information from my mule flow to ajax.[image]
For example if i have a boolean variable in my flow, for the true value, i can show the image "play" and if it's false i can show the image "pause". Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want example to send the payload from your AJAX file to your Mule flow, there are plenty examples available..
For example, here :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/Flight+Reservation+Example

is a great example which uses **Ajax** with **Mule** and **send** information from Ajax file to the Mule flow using **JSON** payload, which is then parsed and used in mule flow using **json-to-object-transformer**..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The example is for the entreprise edition and for sending data from ajax to my flow i have already did it. what i want now is the inverse. Sending data from mule flow to ajax.

Comment: If you check the application properly.. you will find it is sending the response to the Ajax file back

Comment: Sorry I didn't see what do you mean.

Comment: If you check the .js files , you will see the payload is send to the Mule flow in each method using mule.rpc(), where JSON request response is a parameter.. check the entire code ... from Mule flow you need to send the json response to the ajax using Groovy script and then `<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>`

Comment: for the function mule.rpc(), i used it in my example please check the link http://pastebin.com/a8mtwqzR and i had already tried to use groovy but i don't know how to get informtion in the ajax page have i to parse something i don't have any idea